# Trouble passing a function pointer to a method from main in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, unique-ptr

I have the following set up:

poster.h

```
template<class T>
class Poster
{
private:
    unique_ptr<Poster<T>> testPtr = nullptr;
public:
    void post(void (*callback_function)(T), T data)
    {           
        post2(testPtr, callback_function, data);
    }

    void post2(unique_ptr<Poster<T>> p, void (*callback_function)(T), T data)
    {
        callback_function(data);
    }
};
...
```

Then in main.cpp i have the following

```
void output(int x)
{
    std::cout << x;
}

int main()
{
    Poster<int> p;
    int x = 5;  
    p.post(output, x);
}
```

Every time i try to build this i get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2280   'std::unique_ptr<Poster<int>,std::default_delete<Poster<int>>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<Poster<int>,std::default_delete<Poster<int>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I am not sure why this is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `unique_ptr`, as the name suggests, cannot be copied. So `post2(testPtr, call_back_function, data)` isn't valid. Change `post2` to take its `unique_ptr` argument by reference.

Comment: Or simply pass a raw pointer.  For non-owning pointers, this is fine.  What's that parameter for anyway, you're not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `post2()`, you take `unique_ptr<Poster<T>>` *by value*. That only works if you pass it an rvalue reference ('temporary', or something in `std::move()`).

From your example it's not apparent if you really need unique *ownership* inside `post2()` (not generally, but in the function). If you don't need ownership, you might take `unique_ptr<Poster<T>>& p`, or even simply just `Poster<T>& p`. If you want ownership to be transferred, and thus `testPtr` to be emptied, you can write in `post()`: `post2(std::move(testPtr2), ...);`